# Calculating area within a curve

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am measuring the current that passes through a sample as a vary the voltage over it. The result is a current-voltage plot like this

https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/joeb/9/1/graphic/j_joeb-2018-0023_fig_004.jpg

I want to calculate the area within the curve of the first half period (part of the curve in the first quadrant). Not sure what the best way to do this in python. I have tried to write some code that finds pairs with same x-coordinate and subtracts the bottom y-value from the top y-value, and iterates over all the points in the first quadrant.

```
def LobeAreaByPeriod(all_periods_I):
    print('Starting Lobe area by period')
    LobeArea = []
    for period in all_periods_I:
        halfperiod = round(len(period)/2)
        duration = round(halfperiod/2)
        area = 0
        for i in range(duration):
            area += (period[i] - period[halfperiod - i])
        LobeArea.append(area)
    return LobeArea
```

I am not certain the pairs will be located directly above each other this way and I find it difficult to check it the answer is really correct. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate area within a curve you're going to have to do some sort of approximation. Depending on your necessity of precision the method you choose will vary. I like the trapezoidal rule. Numpy has an implementation that is quite nice.

np.trapz

Comment: Okay thanks, so I guess they way to do it would be to subtract the bottom area from the total area. I'll try that!